# Primefaces dataGrid displaying too many items with rows and columns set

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datagrid

In my example, the number of rows for the Primefaces `dataGrid` was set to 5, and columns was set to 2. The rendered table shows 6 items however.

This mostly went unnoticed, until we realized that the button on the 6th item did not work - most likely because it hadn't been bound to an event?

As a minimal example, with an XHTML of (not showing `h:head`, etc elements):

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
       <p:dataGrid value="#{testBean.theStrings}" var="theString" rows="5" columns="2">
           <p:commandButton action="#{testBean.printOut(theString)}" value="#{theString}"/>
       </p:dataGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

And a backing bean of

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable
{
  private List<String> theStrings;

  @PostConstruct
  public void setup() {
    System.out.println("Setting up array");
    theStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      theStrings.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
  }

  public List<String> getTheStrings()
  {
    return theStrings;
  }

  public void printOut(String theString) {
    System.out.println(theString);
  }
}
```

This will render out 6 buttons, labelled 0-5, but only the button labelled 5 does not trigger the system out.

What is happening here? Shouldn't rows have capped the number of items at 5? Increasing the number of rows to 6 does not change the visual output, but the final button begins to work.

Comment: Reproduced. I'd say that this is just a corner case bug. Having an odd amount of rows against an even amount of columns is in first place unexpected in design perspective. Why? Did you really intend to hide the last item from this particular presentation? (and thus end up with a visually "incomplete" grid). You could try reporting an issue to PF guys, but I won't expect a high prio here.

Comment: It was from some confusion about what rows meant in this context - we were thinking table rows, but obviously it actually refers to data rows.

Comment: Indeed, it also got me confused.

Comment: I've actually found this issue  in their open issues, I'll just add details to it. Link for anyone else wanting to track: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6251&q=datagrid&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary#makechanges

Comment: 2013? Clearly not a high prio ;)

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem top of their agenda :) Found the issue in the renderer, I'll just set the right row count on my end for now though.

Comment: Lots of way more prominent issues that are not high prio ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I was facing same issues and figured out that it’s because your column is 3 and rows is 5, so 5/3 = 1.6666… After testing, the results show that if rows/column output an **Integer**, the `dataGrid` will work well.

I’m not sure *why* this is, but it seems to address the problem.